# HTML2PDF: Words being cut off/running off in PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, html2pdf

Some of my words in my file are being cut off in the PPDF. I can see that the words are there, but not properly wrapping.

My output looks like:

[image]

Here is a snippit of my code:

```
            <table>
                <tr align=''>
                    <td colspan='5' class='heading'>Corporate URC Use Only</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Consult Determination<span class='required'></span>:</td>
                    <td><strong>";
                    if(isset($updated_history) && !is_null($updated_history)){
                        $html .= $data['original_decision'];
                    }
                    else{
                        $html .= $data['final_decision'];
                    }

                    $html .="</strong></td>

                </tr>
                </table>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Notes:</td>
                        <td><strong>" . $data['notes'] . "</strong></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

My html2pdf implementation is pretty straight forward:

```
require_once("../include/html2pdf/html2pdf.class.php");
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P','A4','en');
$html2pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('real');     

$html2pdf->WriteHTML($html);
$html2pdf->Output($c_file, "F");
```

EDIT: Here is a link to a sample pdf exhibiting this behavior.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/h91g40bo4b2cmlw/Test_T_2312321.pdf?dl=0

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you provided a (link to a) sample PDF exhibiting this behaviour...

Comment: You can use css to set boundaries for html2pdf. try to add a `<style></style>` to the page you try to pdfy. You can easily google the mm sizes of a standard A4 and set width and height as `mm`   inside your style tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like...

1. ...either your PDF's `/MediaBox` is more narrow than A4 (which is 595 points),
2. ...or your PDF's drawing/writing of `/Contents` code does not respect the A4 width and draws/writes beyond it.

You should check if your code utilizes a (probably hidden) setting that sets the page width (or complete page size) to letter (which would be 612x792 points).

To test my assumption, you could replace the `A4` in your html2pdf implementation by `letter` or `Letter`...

---

*(If you provide a [link to a] PDF created by your code it would be a lot easier to debug. What I wrote above is [almost] pure speculation.)*

---

### Update

After having looked at the source code of the PDF provided in the link of the update to the OP, I can say this:

1. I unpacked the `/Content` streams of the file in order to see PDF page drawing operators as ASCII, using this command:

   ```
   qpdf --qdf --object-streams=disable document.pdf q.pdf
   ```
2. Now the newly generated `q.pdf` is easily opened in a good text editor (like VIm, Emacs or Notepad++).
3. The following line prints some text on the page:

   ```
    BT                     \
      /F2 10.00 Tf         \
    ET                     \
    [....]                 \
    q                      \
      0.000 0.000 0.000 rg \
        BT                 \
          0    Tr          \
          0.00 w           \
        ET                 \
        BT                 \
          50.00 359.19 Td  \
          [(Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore)] TJ \
        ET                 \
   Q
   ```

This code snippets prints a very long line of text with a font internally named as `/F2` (which in turn is mapped to `/Helvetica-Bold` elsewhere in the file), sized `10` points, starting at coordinates `x=50, y=359.19`.

However, this long text line does not fit into the page's width given with `/MediaBox`, defined as `[0 0 595 842]` (which is in PostScript points, and represents A4).

It would fit into a width of `635` (even leaving some small margin on the right edge).

<sub>(You could also make the text fit to the current page width by down-sizing the text, eg. `/F2 9.00 Tf`. But this would still leave the long horizontal lines of your drawn boxes spill beyond the right page border...)</sub>

*The overall source code of this PDF is, BTW, in some places very inefficient (for example it contains `BT /F1 10.00 Tf ET 1.000 g` more than 1000 times, but this code does exactly... nothing! It only defines the font to be used as the internal name `/F1` and the font size as 10 points).*

You can edit the original PDF with a text editor easily:

1. Search for the string `/MediaBox`. It appears twice in the PDF, once for each page.
2. Replace its current value of `[0 0 595.28 841.89]` by a new value of `[0 0 635.00 841.89]`.
3. Save the edited file.
4. Open it in your favorite PDF viewer.

Now you'll see that the page contents also fit into the page's width (which now is `635` points (== `22.4` cm; the original value of `595` points is equivalent to `21.0` cm).

You'll also see that it is not only some long text lines which didn't fit into the page width -- the same is true for some of the horizontal lines drawn for the boxes.

Here is a screenshot of the edited PDF file, showing how the new `/MediaBox` now is able to hold all the page content within its boundaries:

[image: so#29217840.png]

Comment: I've added a link to a sample pdf.

Comment: I don't know if this is correct answer, but i definitely appreciate your walk-trough-this-case :)

Comment: @PaulTomkiel: What makes you doubt about the correctness of my answer?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle - by that i meant that i don't understand problem itself, but just wanted to appreciate your work :)

Comment: @PaulTomkiel: Thanks :)   -- You could still try to replicate my steps and then possibly understand better.

Comment: @KurtPfeifle - when i'll need it, i'll definitely be following your steps!